# Getting Error 400 When Calling A Web Api Method Using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to call a local Web Api method using Ajax. So I have a basic web api app running on visual studio on my local machine. Here's my ajax call

```
let RegisterUserVM = new Object();
RegisterUserVM.Name = name;
RegisterUserVM.Username = username;
RegisterUserVM.Password = password;

$.ajax({
            url: mURL + "api/Default/RegisterUser",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(RegisterUserVM),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp"
          }).done(function( msg ) {
            console.log("Done function");
            console.log(msg);
          }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            console.log("Fail function");
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
          });
    }
```

I have a simple Web api method as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public string RegisterUser(/*RegisterUserVM registerUserVM*/ string Name, string username, string Password)
{
   return "";
}
```

As you can see I have tried passing the object and parametes via the query string but I still keep getting an 400 error bad request when I try and call this method via ajax from jQuery. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

fix ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: mURL + "/api/Default/RegisterUser",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(RegisterUserVM),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
            success: function( msg ) {
            console.log("Done function");
            console.log(msg);
            },
          error: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            console.log("Fail function");
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
          }
          });
```

and action

```
[HttpPost]
public string RegisterUser([FromBody] RegisterUserVM registerUserVM)
{
   return "";
}
```

you will need to create a view model

```
public class RegisterUserVM 
{
public string Name {get; set;}
... ans so on
}
```

or you can try this too

```
$.ajax({
            url: mURL + "/api/Default/RegisterUser",
            type: "POST",
            data: { registerUserVM :  RegisterUserVM },
          
            success: function( msg ) {
            console.log("Done function");
            console.log(msg);
            },
          error: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            console.log("Fail function");
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
          }
          });
```

and remove [frombody]

```
[HttpPost]
public string RegisterUser(RegisterUserVM registerUserVM)
{
   return "";
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your suggestions still getting that error. On investigating dev tools on chrome this is the actual url that gets passed https://localhost:44397/api/Default/RegisterUser?callback=jQuery3600376904385472129_1630247542624&registerUserVM%5BName%5D=tyron&registerUserVM%5BUsername%5D=tyronn&registerUserVM%5BPassword%5D=asdasdsa&_=1630247542625, that does not look normal to me at all what's going on there? Also when I put this request through postman with ssl https://localhost:44397/api/Default/RegisterUser?Name=tyron&Username=tyronn&Password=asdasdsa it hits the method in the web api,

Comment: @ShatterStar there is a typo in ajax , replace "method" by "type" and try again

Comment: @ShatterStar You have really strange URLs, your urls should be https://localhost:44397/api/Default/RegisterUser. Do you use something to change url?

Comment: Hi, I've changed method to type and still get the same error. Yes that query string is really strange. No I didn't use anything to change the url in anyway it's the normal ajax constructor as above.

Comment: @ShatterStar Try to clean a browser cashe

Comment: I've got dev tools open with the cache disabled

Comment: @ShatterStar Did you try both syntaxes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236543/discussion-between-shatterstar-and-serge).

Comment: @ShatterStar I don' t know what is your tools shows, but you created the  strange url in postman too

Comment: No I didn't here's my url in postman https://localhost:44397/api/Default/RegisterUser?Name=tyron&Username=tyronn&Password=pass1